# Getting a timeout pushing a repository to local GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created a local GitLab instance (GitLab 13.10 in Ubuntu 20) and want to import but not mirror a project from GitHub.  In this instance openwrt. I created the project in the GitLab instance and then tried to push to it.

I ran:

```
git clone https://git.openwrt.org/openwrt/openwrt.git
git remote rename origin old-origin
git remote add origin http://gitlab.local/group/project.git
git push -u origin --all
```

And I got:

```
Counting objects: 533132, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (142241/142241), done.
Writing objects: 100% (533132/533132), 162.16 MiB | 6.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 533132 (delta 369475), reused 530420 (delta 368128)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (369475/369475), done.
remote: Checking connectivity: 533132, done.
remote: GitLab: Push operation timed out
remote:
remote: Timing information for debugging purposes:
remote: Running checks for ref: master
remote: Checking if you are allowed to push... (22.92ms)
remote: Checking if default branch is being deleted... (0.77ms)
remote: Checking if you are force pushing to a protected branch... (579.48ms)
remote: Checking if you are allowed to push to the protected branch... (21.38ms)
remote: Scanning repository for blobs stored in LFS and verifying their files have been uploaded to GitLab... (cancelled after 29409.76ms)
To http://gitlab.local/group/project.git
 ! [remote rejected]       master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://gitlab.local/group/project.git'
```

I've done the same with another project and the push worked fine, so I think there's something it doesn't like with *this* project. There are 9210 files in the project, so I've assumed it's something to do with lots of files.

Things I've tried:

- I've gone through just about every log I can find, but there are no errors on the server.
- I've increased all the timeouts I could find, but it didn't seem to help
- Increased memory to 8192MB
- Increased the puma worker max memory from 865MB to 4096MB
- Using git instead of http (tried that first...)
- setting the lfs endpoint to use http rather than https (`git config --add lfs.url "http://gitlab.local/group/project.git/info/lfs"` though I'm not sure this did anything, setting it to "wibble:wobble" didn't make it fail in any spectacular way)
- Googling the errors

I don't think there should be any files in there on LFS, the largest file is 4KB. But since the error mentions LFS I thought I'd play with those settings.

Any help appreciated; I'm tearing my hair out.

Answer (score 2):

After much trying different things, and asking on the GitLab forums, it seems the solution is to disable the `lfs_check` using the rails console.

As root on the gitlab server, run:

```
gitlab-rails console
```

wait for the initialisation to complete:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ruby:         ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
 GitLab:       13.10.0 (5eafdaf7b07) FOSS
 GitLab Shell: 13.17.0
 PostgreSQL:   12.5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Feature.enable(:lfs_check)
Loading production environment (Rails 6.0.3.4)
irb(main):001:0>
```

then issue the command:

```
irb(main):001:0> Feature.disable(:lfs_check)
```

and it should return:

```
=> true
```

After which the push succeeded.

This is fixed using a "feature flag" which is a "temporary fix", so should at some point have a better solution than this.